# How to get a non-shuffled train_test_split in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

If I want a random train/test split, I use the sklearn helper function:

```
In [1]: from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
   ...: train_test_split([1,2,3,4,5,6])
   ...:
Out[1]: [[1, 6, 4, 2], [5, 3]]
```

What is the most concise way to get a non-shuffled train/test split, i.e.

```
[[1,2,3,4], [5,6]]
```

**EDIT** Currently I am using

```
train, test = data[:int(len(data) * 0.75)], data[int(len(data) * 0.75):]
```

but hoping for something a little nicer. I have opened an issue on sklearn
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8844

**EDIT 2:** My PR has been merged, in scikit-learn version 0.19, you can pass the parameter `shuffle=False` to `train_test_split` to obtain a non-shuffled split.

Comment: I was about to add comment about using `shuffle=False` parameter and then saw your edit :)

Answer (score 39):

I'm not adding much to Psidom's answer except an easy to copy paste function:

```
def non_shuffling_train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2):
    i = int((1 - test_size) * X.shape[0]) + 1
    X_train, X_test = np.split(X, [i])
    y_train, y_test = np.split(y, [i])
    return X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test
```

Update:
At some point this feature became built in, so now you can do:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)
```

Answer (score 10):

All you need to do is to set the shuffle parameter to False and stratify parameter to None:

```
    In [49]: train_test_split([1,2,3,4,5,6],shuffle = False, stratify = None)
    Out[49]: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: hey mayank actually `stratify=None` is the default (see my "Edit 2" in the original question)

Answer (score 5):

Use `numpy.split`:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

np.split(data, [4])           # modify the index here to specify where to split the array
# [array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6])]
```

In case you want to split by a percentage, you can calculate the split index from the shape of *data*:

```
data = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
p = 0.6

idx = int(p * data.shape[0]) + 1      # since the percentage may end up to be a fractional 
                                      # number, modify this as you need, usually shouldn't
                                      # affect much if data is large
np.split(data, [idx])
# [array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6])]
```

Comment: thanks, this almost looks like what i want but what if i don't know the value i want to spit on? i.e. say i just want to do a 60/40 split?

Comment: hmm yeah i was hoping to avoid something like this but maybe is not possiblein in this case do you think it might be clearer to just do `data[:int(len(data)*p)], data[int(len(data)*p):]`

Comment: is `len` slower than `shape`?

Comment: I think they are pretty close as for performance. A brief timing shows that `len` is actually faster than `shape` on an array of `1e8`.