# How to split the data set without train_test_split()?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn

I need to split my dataset into training and testing. 
I need the last 20% of the values for testing and the first 80% for training. 
I have currently used the 'train_test_split()' but it picks the data randomly instead of the last 20%. How can I get the last 20% for testing and the first 80% for training?
My code is as follows:

```
numpy_array = df.as_matrix()
X = numpy_array[:, 1:26]
y = numpy_array[:, 0]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=20) #I do not want the data to be random.
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a non-shuffled train\_test\_split in sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43838052/how-to-get-a-non-shuffled-train-test-split-in-sklearn)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
train_pct_index = int(0.8 * len(X))
X_train, X_test = X[:train_pct_index], X[train_pct_index:]
y_train, y_test = y[:train_pct_index], y[train_pct_index:]
```

It's one of those situations where it's just better not to involve `sklearn` helpers. Very straightforward, readable, and not dependent on knowing internal options of `sklearn` helpers, which code readers may not have experience with.

Answer (score 0):

I think this Stackoverflow topic answers your question :

[How to get a non-shuffled train_test_split in sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43838052/how-to-get-a-non-shuffled-train-test-split-in-sklearn)

And especially this piece of text :

> in scikit-learn version 0.19, you can pass the parameter shuffle=False to train_test_split to obtain a non-shuffled split.

From the documentation :

> shuffle : boolean, optional (default=True)
>
> Whether or not to shuffle the data before splitting. If shuffle=False then >stratify must be None.

Please tell me if I didn't understand your question correctly