# How do I split the data into the first 808698 rows of the train and the rest as a test?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I have two datasets which are test and train. I gathered them in one csv. I want to split my data for train and test. But it should'nt be random. I need to split first 808699  rows of the train and the rest as a test?

I tried to read two different csv but I couldn't.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,train_size=808698,test_size=121918,random_state=1)
```

```
ValueError: train_size=808698 should be either positive and smaller than the number of samples 121921 or a float in the (0, 1) range
```

Comment: what is the output of `len(x)` or `x.shape`

Comment: If you really want to use train_test_split just assign value **121918/808698** to test_size and delete **train_size**

Comment: easy way is still to define ur set manualy. e.g x_test=line(0 to 808698)

Comment: x have 22 columns @mujjiga

Comment: ı wrote x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.15,random_state=1) but its still randomly :(   @akhetos

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43838052/how-to-get-a-non-shuffled-train-test-split-in-sklearn

Comment: try shuffle=False as an argument, as the doc suggests : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be to use train_test_split (sklearn module) is setting shuffle to False. Shuffle takes priority over the random_state parameter. So, if you set shuffle as FALSE, the first n observations (i.e. 90 rows) in your dataset will go to the train dataset, and the last 10 rows would go to the test dataset. Your code will be:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=121918/930616, shuffle=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have one df, use `iloc` to split them according to what you want:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('...')
train = df.iloc[:808699]
test = df.iloc[808699:]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you read train and test files, check their shapes individually.

train/test.shape should give you an output in this format : (Total no of data points, total number of features)

Shape of train should be (x,y) 
Shape of test should be (x1,y) 
Final Shape of combined dataset should be ((x+x1),y)

Do this for combining them : train.append(test)

Then finally you can split them into X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test based on the size of the combined dataframe.